# Interfacing with PoE wireless network adapter

Tags: networking, wifi, network-interface, ifconfig, iw

I have a collection of external wireless NICs. The vast majority just plug & play via USB, and work as you'd expect, with all the standard utilities; `ifconfig`, `iwconfig`, `ip`, `iw`, etc. New interfaces are typically created (automatically), in the form of `wlan0`, or similar.

Anyway, I decided to try out an adaptor that utilises PoE, and connects to the host's Ethernet port, rather than USB/PCMCIA/PCIe/whatever. So, in this case, it's connected via the native `eth0`, and doesn't appear to be recognised (by the host) as a separate interface unto itself.

Is there a way around this, so I can specify, address, and configure the new interface?

Comment: Are you able to connect to the internet through the PoE?

Comment: Please connect your adapter then add the output of `cat /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate`

Comment: @GAD3R I'll double check, and let you know.